# OpenGL screen postprocessing effects

Tags: opengl, shader, lwjgl

I've built a nice music visualizer using OpenGL in Java. It already looks pretty neat, but I've thought about adding some post processing to it. At the time, it looks like this:

[image: Something like this]

There is already a framebuffer for recording the output, so I have the texture already available. Now I wonder if someone has an idea for some effects. The current Fragment shader looks like this:

```
#version 440

in vec3 position_FS_in;
in vec2 texCoords_FS_in;


out vec4 out_Color;

//the texture of the last Frame by now exactly the same as the output
uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

//available data:
//the average height of the lines seen in the screenshot, ranging from 0 to 1
uniform float mean;
//the array of heights of the lines seen in the screenshot
uniform float music[512];

void main()
{
    vec4 texColor = texture(textureSampler, texCoords_FS_in);
    //insert post processing here
    out_Color = texColor;
}
```

Comment: Is that a spectrum analyzer at the bottom? I've always been fond of the "voiceprint" visualization, where you scroll scanlines from the spectrum analyzer, setting each pixel to the magnitude of that point from the FFT. It makes it easy to identify the notes in a song. It's not a post-processing effect really, so I just commented.

Comment: @doug65536 sorry, but i don't really get your point. Let's say, I have calculated the music[], what should I do to it before I load it to the shader? Maybe some code, please?

Comment: Post processing effects are implemented by reading from the framebuffer and blending something based on the original framebuffer over the original framebuffer. Did you want a tutorial on [OpenGL postprocessing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Post-Processing)? You can't just suddenly do postprocessing where your comment is.

Comment: @doug65536 See, the shader I've provided is the shader that is called after the main part is rendered. My "pipeline" looks like this: Textures + Lines -> PostProcessingFBO -> textureSampler -> postProcessingShader -> Display

Comment: Ah, okay, so that sampler is reading from the rendered frame? Sorry I missed that comment above the sampler.

Comment: @doug65536 exactly, this shader is reading from the last frame (FBO) and writes to the display

Comment: Nothing to add to it but I just wanted to say the visualiser is looking pretty groovy already :)

Comment: @WearyWanderer After I finished the GUI for the presets and managed to export it from eclipse, I will post a link here

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to seeing it!

Comment: @WearyWanderer I've uploaded it now on GitHub. It is still not finished, but it works for the most part. I hope you will contribute to it: https://github.com/Dynamitos/MusicVisualizer/tree/master

Comment: @doug65536 see comment to WearyWanderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most post processing effects vary with time, so it is common to have a uniform that varies with the passage of time. For example, a "wavy" effect might be created by offsetting texture coordinates using `sin(elapsedSec * wavyRadsPerSec + (PI * gl_FragCoord.y * 0.5 + 0.5) * wavyCyclesInFrame)`.

Some "postprocessing" effects can be done very simply, for example, instead of clearing the back buffer with `glClear` you can blend a nearly-black transparent quad over the whole screen. This will create a persistence effect where the past frames fade to black behind the current one.

A directional blur can be implemented by taking multiple samples at various distances from each point, and weighting the closer ones more strongly and summing. If you track the motion of a point relative to the camera position and orientation, it can be made into a motion blur implementation.

Color transformations are very simple as well, simply treat the RGB as though they are the XYZ of a vector, and do interesting transformations on it. Sepia and "psychedelic" colors can be produced this way.

You might find it helpful to convert the color into something like HSV, do transformations on that representation, and convert it back to RGB for the  framebuffer write. You could affect hue, saturation, for example, fading to black and white, or intensifying the color saturation smoothly.

A "smearing into the distance" effect can be done by blending the framebuffer onto the framebuffer, by reading from texcoord that is slightly scaled up from gl_FragCoord, like `texture(textureSampler, (gl_FragCoord * 1.01).xy)`.

On that note, you should not need those texture coordinate attributes, you can use gl_FragCoord to find out where you are on the screen, and use (an adjusted copy of) that for your `texture` call.

Have a look at a few shaders on [GLSLSandbox](http://glslsandbox.com/) for inspiration.

I have done [a simple emulation of the trail effect](http://glslsandbox.com/e#31893.3) on GLSLSandbox. In the real one, the loop would not exist, it would take one sample from a small offset. The "loop" effect would happen by itself because its input includes the output from the last frame. To emulate having a texture of the last frame, I simply made it so I can calculate what the other pixel is. You would read the last-frame texture instead of calling something like pixelAt when doing the trail effect.

You can use the wave instead of my faked sine wave. Use the `uv.x` to select an index, scaled appropriately.

**GLSL**

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform float time;
uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec2 resolution;
const float PI = 3.14159265358979323;// lol ya right, but hey, I memorized it

vec4 pixelAt(vec2 uv)
{
    vec4 result;
    float thickness = 0.05;
    float movementSpeed = 0.4;
    float wavesInFrame = 5.0;
    float waveHeight = 0.3;
    float point = (sin(time * movementSpeed + 
               uv.x * wavesInFrame * 2.0 * PI) *
               waveHeight);
    const float sharpness = 1.40;
    float dist = 1.0 - abs(clamp((point - uv.y) / thickness, -1.0, 1.0));
    float val;
    float brightness = 0.8;

    // All of the threads go the same way so this if is easy
    if (sharpness != 1.0)
        dist = pow(dist, sharpness);

    dist *= brightness;

    result = vec4(vec3(0.3, 0.6, 0.3) * dist, 1.0);

    return result;
}

void main( void ) {

    vec2 fc = gl_FragCoord.xy;
    vec2 uv     = fc / resolution - 0.5;
    vec4 pixel;

    pixel = pixelAt(uv);

    // I can't really do postprocessing in this shader, so instead of
    // doing the texturelookup, I restructured it to be able to compute
    // what the other pixel might be. The real code would lookup a texel
    // and there would be one sample at a small offset, the feedback
    // replaces the loop.
    const float e = 64.0, s = 1.0 / e;
    for (float i = 0.0; i < e; ++i) {
        pixel += pixelAt(uv + (uv * (i*s))) * (0.3-i*s*0.325);
    }
    pixel /= 1.0;

    gl_FragColor = pixel;
}
```

Comment: The trail effect would be cool

Comment: Looks awesome, any ideas for using the music waves or the mean?

Comment: @Dynamitos I added a link to a GLSLSandbox emulation of the feedback (I can't do real feedback for the trail effect so I emulated having a texture lookup). The wave could replace the `sin` call that calculates `point`, and the mean could, perhaps, affect the thickness of the line a bit.

Comment: @doug65536 Looks nice but I don't think it fits the current style. Probably I will add it as a option, but not permanent. One last thing I wanted to know was what you meant in your first comment, where you said something about identifying notes. How would I do that if I have the sine waves in the music[]?

Comment: To do that you need a spectrum analyzer. You need an FFT implementation to convert the time-domain data (wav) into frequency-domain (a list of amplitudes for every frequency). I mistakenly thought the oscilloscope in your screenshot was a spectrum analyzer. I have a github repo with a [C++ spectrum analyzer implementation](https://github.com/doug65536/FastSpectrumAnalyzer) if you want to look. The FFT is the important part.